# How to make Google Assistant pass data to a custom API?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I am trying to use Google Assistant to send a request to my own API, which should include a portion of the user's spoken phrase as a parameter.

For example, if the user says, "Hey Google, Tweet this: I am a developer", I'd like this action to trigger an endpoint like `https://example.com/tweet?text=I%20am%20a%20developer`. Ideally, I would also return the response assistant should give to user from this endpoint.

I have looked into [Conversational Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview), but it appears that it is deprecated. Is there an alternative method of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to make Google Assistant pass data to a custom API was supported previously by Conversational Actions. Since, conversational actions are no longer active you try making use of [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app) as an alternative to make this work.

Comment: Thanks! Is this the only way? As per your solution, the only way to call an API from calling "hey google" is creating a native app, right? Isn't there any other way?